# Inbuilt search and relationship field

Tags: relationships, search

Does the inbuilt search search through the relationship fields?

I am using `simple_form`

Comment: Do you mean does it search through the titles or the entire entry of related entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Search module will *not* look in any related entries when determining if your search terms match a particular entry.